# vue3 performance warning using ref

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

vue is throwing this message:

> Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object. This can
> lead to unnecessary performance overhead, and should be avoided by
> marking the component with `markRaw` or using `shallowRef` instead of
> `ref`.

```js
<template>
      <component v-for="(el, idx) in elements" :key="idx" :data="el" :is="el.component" />
</template>



 setup() {
    const { getters } = useStore()
    const elements = ref([])
    onMounted(() => {
      fetchData().then((response) => {
        elements.value = parseData(response)
      })
    })
    return { parseData }
}
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not simply binding the data?

Comment: i'm binding data inside the v-for

Comment: oh you mean why i'm using the composition api?, i came from react ant it looks much like  what i'm used to. Am i wrong using it in my components?

Answer (score 26):

First, you should **return { elements }** instead of parseData in your setup i think.

---

I solved this issue by marking the objects as **shallowRef** :

```js
import { shallowRef,  ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { EditProfileForm, EditLocationForm, EditPasswordForm} from '@/components/profile/forms'

const profile = shallowRef(EditProfileForm)
const location = shallowRef(EditLocationForm)
const password = shallowRef(EditPasswordForm)

const forms = [profile, location, password]
```

```html
<component v-for="(form, i) in forms" :key="i" :is="form" />
```

So you should shallowRef your components inside your parseData function. I tried markRaw at start, but it made the component non-reactive. Here it works perfectly.

Comment: If I do this, nothing is rendered and I get the following warning `Component is missing template or render function`. If I dont use the shallowRef, component is rendered but i get this other warning ` Vue received a Component which was made a reactive objec`. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem seems to be inside your component. Have you got some code to share ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as @gumlym I am using an icon package [vue-tabler-icons](https://github.com/alex-oleshkevich/vue-tabler-icons) I import the component `import { CheckboxIcon } from 'vue-tabler-icons';` and then when I render it with `<component>` I get the error that gumlym describes

Comment: @gmm same. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 21):

you could manually shallowCopy the result

```
<component v-for="(el, idx) in elements" :key="idx" :data="el" :is="{...el.component}" />
```

Comment: This worked for me , though it is not documented and is so simple ...

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error. I solved it with markRaw. You can read about it [here](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#markraw)!

my code :

```
import { markRaw } from "vue";
import Component from "./components/Component.vue";
data() {
    return {
      Component: markRaw(Component),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had defined a map in the `data` section.

```html
<script>
import TheFoo from '@/TheFoo.vue';

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data: function () {
    return {
      someMap: {
        key: TheFoo
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

The data section can be updated reactively, so I got the console errors. Moving the map to a computed fixed it.

```html
<script>
import TheFoo from '@/TheFoo.vue';

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  computed: {
    someMap: function () {
      return {
        key: TheFoo
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this warning while displaying an SVG component; from what I deduced, Vue was showing the warning because it assumes the component is reactive and in some cases the reactive object can be huge causing performance issues.

The [`markRaw`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#markraw) API tells Vue not to bother about reactivity on the component, like so - `markRaw(<Your-Component> or regular object)`

Answer (score 1):

I also meet this problem today,and here is my solution to solve it:

```js
setup() {
  const routineLayoutOption = reactive({
    board: {
      component: () => RoutineBoard,
    },
    table: {
      component: () => RoutineTable,
    },
    flow: {
      component: () => RoutineFlow,
    },
  });
}
```

I set the component variant as the result of the function.
And in the ,bind it like compoennt()

```js
    <component
        :is="routineLayoutOption[currentLayout].component()"
      ></component>
```